# getting join results in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have indexed two document types in solr viz analysis and issue_summery

The fields for analysis:

```
   doc_id
   doc_type
   title
   description
```

The fields for issue_summery:

```
  doc_id
  doc_type
  issue_parent_id (this is fk from analysis [doc_id])
  summery
  issue_id (this comes from another table)
```

analysis has one to many relationship with issue_summery.

I am using a join query as follows:

```
q={!join+from=issue_parent_id+to=doc_id}doc_type:issue_summery
```

and it works as I expected. Now when I search with specific issue_id

```
&q={!join+from=issue_parent_id+to=doc_id}doc_type:issue_summery+AND+issue_id:(+issue_103)
```

This query returns results with issue id = 103

But when I query by multiple issue ids like

```
&q={!join+from=issue_parent_id+to=doc_id}doc_type:issue_summery+AND+nature_of_the_issues_summery:(issue_322+issue_82)&rows=20&start=0&json.nl=map
```

It returns results where issue_id = issue_322 OR issue_id=issue_82

I am expecting ANDing here ie. I need to get those analysis docs which contains issue_id = issue_322 **AND** issue_82 *rather than:* issue_id = issue_322  **OR** issue_82

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your reference, summary is customarily spelled with an 'a' as summary, rather than an 'e' as summery.  Summary means a synopsis or representation. Summery means 'summer like'.  A cocktail with a pineapple slice and an umbrella on top is 'Summery'.  An abstract is a kind of 'Summary'.

Comment: Thanks Tim for edits.

Comment: Why not just put in the `AND` keyword there?

Comment: I tried with AND but , it didn't work.

Comment: did you try issue_322+AND+issue_82 ? What is the error you are getting in the solr console?

Comment: nothing, it returns empty results

Comment: q={!join+from=issue_parent_id+to=doc_id}doc_type:issue_summery&fq=nature_of_the_issues_summery:(issue_322+AND+issue_82)&rows=20&start=0&json.nl=map

Comment: already tried this,no luck!

Comment: btw why are u expedcting AND here? Is issue_id a multivalued field? Can you post a sample dataset as an example ?